# How to programmatically blur an area in a movie (in python)?

Tags: python, movie

I have a movie, and I want to produce a new movie out of it with an area blurred (e.g. an object, a writing or a face). The area is moving, so I must have fine control of the current frame and move the position of the blur area accordingly. Blur is an option, but also a dark mask is fine too.

Now, I have a question open at superuser on which software to use, but since I suspect I will have to buy adobe premiere to do something like this, and I don't want to shell out a kidney for something I have to do once, I am thinking about coding it myself in python.

What are the best libraries available for this task ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the avisynth realtime video processing language.  It is basically a scripting language for video.  You should be able to specify a moving mask with it, and it will probably end up being a lot easier than trying to do the processing in a general purpose language.

Comment: @Eric : osx here :( thanks anyway

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220866/best-video-manipulation-library-for-python for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Definetively you'll need to use OpenCV, mainly due to performance issues you may have to process it in Python. See the [Smooth function](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_image_filtering.html#smooth) from the [Image Filtering](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_image_filtering.html#image-filtering) section of the Python [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html) from OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Blurring is easy, either Avisynth or openCV will do that. If you need to track the position of a moving object then avisynth requires you to manually select the position, you should be able to write a decent object tracker in openCV easily.

I don't know of any free video editors that do this automatically - if you you only need to do it once you could use a trial version of something like premiere.