# Trim (remove frames from) a video using Python

Tags: python, video, frames, trim

I would like to trim - cut off frames at the beginning and end - a video that can be in a variety of different formats, and then save the trimmed video.

Are there any libraries or suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220866/best-video-manipulation-library-for-python offers something appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module of python to extract video thumbnails, but it seems ffmpeg can do pretty much anything.

Once you install ffmpeg, you can trim off the first second of video like so

```
> ffmpeg -i sample.mov  -ss 1 trim.mov
```

So using the subprocess module of python

```
import subprocess
seconds = "1" # has to be a string
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', inputfilename, '-ss', seconds, outputfilename])
```

will take off the first second. For specific frames, there are flags like -vframes and -dframes, but I haven't actually used them. Documentation of [ffmpeg here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

There's also [pyffmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/), a python wrapper for ffmpeg. But I haven't used it.

Comment: It works if you have a saved video. I want to trim live video using my webcam. I have written the code. It is saving frames in a video and i want to remove the first frame after 30 seconds of video.